# Как получить "оригинальное" исключение возникшее при сохранении в EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В своем проекте использую EF версии 6. В очередной раз у меня возник вопрос, как добраться до *реального* исключения возникшего при сохранении данных(`SaveChanges()`)

Собственно вопрос в том, есть ли иной способ кроме рекурсии получить *оригинальный* exception?

Под рекурсивным способом я подразумеваю погружение внутрь через свойство `InnerException` до тех пор пока там не будет `null`?

Comment: Да, надо рекурсивно погружаться, а в чем проблема?

Comment: да собственно ни в чем, просто спросил вдруг это делается иначе. Вопрос стоит удалить? или лучше ответить с указанием того как получить код ошибки SQL?

Comment: Пусть висит, может кто еще что напишет. Укажите метку языка — будет больше просмотров, я сам чисто случайно натолкнулся на вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

получение *оригинального* исключения при помощи рекурсии выглядит так:

```
public Exception getOriginalException(Exception e)
{
    if(e.InnerException == null)
        return e;
    return getOriginalException(e.InnerException);
}
```

P.S. для получение более подробной информации о возникшем исключении необходимо экземпляр *оригинального* исключения привести к типу `SqlException`, что позволит получить номер ошибки, которую можно расшифровать на [сайте](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-2017)